# Is it still possible to "pin" a Gmail message?

Tags: gmail

I read at https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6067587?hl=en-GB that one can "pin" an email message.

I can't find how or where to do that.

Is that feature a thing of the past?  If it still exists, where should I be looking?

Answer (score 4):

**[https://inbox.google.com/?](https://inbox.google.com/?pli=1)**

- In your inbox, go to a bundled labels like "Promos" or "Social," or a time section like "Today"
- Pin any emails you still want to get to.
- In the top right, select **Sweep**. Make sure you choose the sweep icon for that label or time section.
- To see a list of only your pinned emails and reminders, click the switch at the top of your inbox **Pin Slider** [image]. This lets you focus on just the things you need to do, without being distracted by the rest of your emails.

**[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZ7Ufce5XQU)**

**NOTE:** if you are on the latest Gmail, then there are no pins. there is a similar future - **Add to Tasks** and it can be found under **More** button after you select an email

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to achieve a result that's similar to "Pinning" via the settings of the inbox. Basically configuring it like in the image below makes all the starred messages act as "Pinned" - They appear on the top of the inbox and can't be removed from there without unstarring the message:

[image]

I've posted more detailed instructions here:

https://medium.com/@vitalyb/using-pinning-from-googles-inbox-in-gmail-444dedc785d1

Answer (score 1):

That's currently a feature of [**Inbox by Gmail**](https://inbox.google.com), not old-fashioned [Gmail](https://gmail.com). *Inbox* uses slightly different paradigms for managing your email, although it uses the same pool of email messages.

That's why you're not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

all emails pinned in Inbox can be found using label:pinned in search box

then you can use stars and labels in gmail to simulate this feature

https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/9117840?p=transition_to_gmail&visit_id=636882569578368657-764591886&rd=1

Answer (score 0):

I have the Firefox Inbox add on.  This is very helpful.  However I don't know if the awesome PIN feature will stop working after March.  I plan on using it as long as I can.  This feature is perfect for quick access without having to navigate throughout gmail either on web or app.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/user/14221868/